# Delphi - combo box search in database using sql queries

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-7

This is the error I get when I run the code below. I'm not too sure what's wrong any help is appreciated

[image]

```
procedure TFSearchMember.btnSearchClick(Sender: TObject);
var buttonSelected:integer;
WhereTextSelection,WhereFieldSelection:string;
begin

WhereFieldSelection:=cboWhereField.Text;
WhereTextSelection:=txtWhere.Text;

adoQuery1.Parameters[0].Value:=WhereTextSelection;
adoQuery1.Open;
ADOQuery1.Requery;

txtWhere.Text:='';
cboWhereField.Text:='';


  if ADOQuery1.RecordCount=0 then
  begin
    buttonSelected:=MessageDlg('Record not found.', mtError, [mbOK],0);
    if buttonSelected = mrOK then
    Exit;
  end;
```

I also have this in the ADOQuery SQL property

[image]

Comment: Please include the text of your error message, and the text of your query within the question.

Comment: Is there a field WhereFieldSelection in table tblMembers in the SQL database?

The error message might be hiding the true problem.

Comment: Why are you calling `adoQuery1.Open;` and then **immediately** calling `adoQuery1.Requery;`? Use some common sense: if you've **just** opened the query, why in the world would you think you need to requery it again? *Let's see. I'll turn the doorknob on my front door, push the door open, and then immediately push it again without doing anything in between.* Does that make *any kind of sense* to you?

Comment: @KenWhite Yea i understand thanks.

Comment: @penarthur66 no it is the result of what is in-putted into the combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question doesn't say so, I'd suspect that you're trying to allow the user to both select the field to use in the `WHERE` (from `cboWhereField`) and the value (from `txtWhere`). If that's the case, you have to update the SQL first before you can assign the parameter, as both are changing.

Something like this should work (in a basic sense):

```
procedure TFSearchMember.btnSearchClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  SQLBase = 'SELECT * FROM tblMembers WHERE %s = :SearchValue';
begin
  if AdoQuery1.Active then
    AdoQuery1.Close;
  AdoQuery1.SQL.Text := Format(SQLBase, [cboWhereField.Text]);
  AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('SearchValue').Value := txtWhere.Text;
  AdoQuery1.Open;

  txtWhere.Text:='';
  cboWhereField.Text:='';

  if not ADOQuery1.IsEmpty then
  begin
    // No need for if test here, as you're only offering one value.
    // MessageDlg can't return anything other than mrOK
    MessageDlg('Record not found.', mtError, [mbOk], 0);
    Exit;
  end;

  // Your other code
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that not all code is shown, because it seems that you try to create dynamic SQL where the "WhereFieldSelection" can be changed to whatever is shown in the combobox.  If you change the SQL.Text property (e.g. to use "Forename") of the ADOQuery AFTER the parameter value is set, the value of the parameter is lost, and you will have to reset it.  Also, the Requery, is not necessary, as Ken White mentioned.